# Is there any way to get ooyala player version or player information using ooyala java scripts API

Tags: ooyala

I want get player version of Ooyala player like Player V2, V3 or V4.

Is there any api available to get player version or player information.

For example to get asset title, you can use the following code

```
ooyala_player.getTitle()
```

How to get know which player i am using player v3? or v4? using api.

I know the player v3 and player v4 has different UI other than this any difference in player v3 and v4?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Chinya, any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

Chinya,

Depends on the player version, they have slightly different APIs.

Check out [API Docs](http://apidocs.ooyala.com) site for the most updated versions.

A quick search turns out that player v4 has a [`getVersion()`](http://apidocs.ooyala.com/player_v4_js/OO.Player.html#getVersion) function.

Answer (score 0):

Non-programmatic:

- Visual difference (as you mentioned)
- The JS pulled down references the version number.
- When V3 JS executes it outputs to console:

  - "V3 version source: default"

Programmatic:

- V3:

  - OO.__internal.playerParams.core_version;
- V4:

  - OO.VERSION.core;

I'm sure there are other ways as well.

You could also validate based on the existence of top level properties in OO, given they are fairly different.

This is assuming that you don't have a hodge podge of v3 and v4 player on the same page - let me know if that assumption is wrong.

Hope that's helpful. I would be curious to know the use case!